# How to sync Javascript with CSS transitions to create a "onComplete" callback, when the transition is overriden by another?

Tags: javascript, css-transitions

I am trying to sync Javascript with CSS transitions, and I have done it right.
I basically created a callback that fires after X seconds, and everything works fine IF the transition completes normally. However, when the transition is interrupted BEFORE completion by another transition, like when you leave the mouse from a div when you're altering its width (for example, the div is 100px wide, mouseover -> 300px mouseout -> 100px. You mouse-leave the div before it reaches 300px, the transition DO NOT calculate the full-duration!), I don't know how to calculate the new duration.

I have tried the trasitionend event but is currently an instable solution to me.

CSS

```
div {
  width: 100px;height: 100px;background: red;
  transition: width 2s;
}

div:hover {
  width: 300px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

JS

```
let mydiv = document.getElementById('mydiv')
let i = 0;
var callback = function() {
 i++;
  mydiv.innerHTML = 'done ' + i;
}

mydiv.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  setTimeout(callback, 2000+10);
});

mydiv.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  setTimeout(callback, 2000+10);
});
```

As you can see, the callback is broken when you do not wait for the transition to fully complete, of course.
Is there a method to calculate the "cut" duration from the previous start point, in order to set a proper duration for the timeout, instead of using the "static" css duration?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In what way is transitionend unstable. What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: I’d add the transition class on JS mouseenter event, and remove it on JS mouseleave. I think syncing two independent processes on “timestamp” won’t be good.

Comment: @MarkFisher the transitionend event fires multiple times. if you transition more than one property, you get a lot of transitionend callback calls. For example:

`
var i = 0;
      transition.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
        console.log(++i);
        console.log('Transition ended');
      });
`

The "i" value is unstable.

Comment: @saga Can you not detect in the callback which property it is being fired for using the propertyName property of the TransitionEvent object - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TransitionEvent

Comment: @MarkFisher Not in every cases. Because if my code is used by another developer, i don't know which CSS property he would alter. 
In addition, transitionend event is unstable because it fires unbound from the transition which fired it. You can not know what event fired it. Of course you can add/remove the event in the mouseevents but it would be a real mess, not reusable code.